# Image Upload Issue in Laravel 5.3.6 When i upload the file it return me no file

Tags: php, html, laravel

**Form**

```
<form files ="true" action="{{ route('mynewproject') }}">
   <input  type="file" name="projectimage" id="projectimage">
 <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**DashbordController**

This is my controller to check only the input has file or not but it gives me no files:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\project;
use Input;
use Image;
use File;

class DashbordController extends Controller
{

   public function projectAdded(Request $request){
    if(Input::hasFile('projectimage')){
    return $request->projectimage;
  }else{
   return 'no file';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies with your `form` HTML element. The attribute `files` isn't recognized. You're likely confusing it with the attribute you're able to pass to the Laravel Collective Form/Html package, which upon output converts adds the `enctype` attribute to the form opening tag.

You should change your `form` tag to this:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ route('mynewproject') }}">
```

Notice the `enctype` attribute. That should allow you to upload files.

Comment: Thanks but not solve it gives me an error that method GET,POST is not allowed

Comment: This solves it - but the next error you are getting is due to an error in your routes.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php 

public function projectAdded(Request $request){
    if($request->hasFile('projectimage')){
    return $request->projectimage;
  }else{
   return 'no file';
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: Use above code  and check with $request->hasFile('projectimage')